# Fading out thousands of img data points with javascript canvas and d3

Tags: javascript, java, animation, d3.js, canvas

The problem lies with performance. I have implemented a real time scatter plot graph that is built with a Java Websocket, Javascript canvas, and the d3 framework. I mostly just use d3 for dynamic data binding with the axis, and scales. The drawing happens with canvas for better performance.

But here is the issue.

Every point that gets plotted. The point has to wait 5 seconds, then fade out. This creates a animation like effect as it runs through the requestanimationframe(), so data points are not static on the graph. The backend will be constantly pushing data through the websocket so the frontend (javascript) will need to keep up, it will only stop pushing data when a user sends a new command to the server to stop the websocket loop.

The issue is having multiple animation frames happening at once. My current algorithm goes like this. I use a d3.timer from d3 which is a performance animation loop. This gives a smooth fade out, by decreasing alpha by 1 each loop until alpha < 5. then quits. This will happen for each data point. The performance for this actually works great and looks amazing, but once i start adding more graphs and functions to the webpage, performance will start to bog down. It can keep up 38 fps with only the scatter plot. But when implementing another graph in the same animation loop, I'm starting to see it deteriorate. I've tried using a setTimeout() for each data point to be called repeatedly every millisecond or so, but it won't give the same great animation effect as what d3.timer is giving me.

Does anyone have a better way or a idea on how to make thousands of data points fade out given the time interval and the time they were plotted from being pushed by the back end, using image data? A way to keep my performance between 28-40 fps at a minimum?

Here are my steps and code below.

- Plot a point
- Set a timeout for 5 seconds
- Once the timeout is done, run d3.timer ( a d3 performance animation loop)
- Fade the data point out by redrawing with alpha decreased by 1
- Once alpha < 5. Exit animation loop.

Here is the code:

```
scatterBase.scatter.context.putImageData(imgData, cx[k], cy[k]);

//5 second decay for now...
var _timer;
var _timeout;

_timeout = d3.timeout(function(elapsed) {

    _timer = (d3.timeout(function(elap) {
        scatterBase.timer.push(_timer);
        scatterBase.lifeCycle(imgData, cx[k], cy[k], a -= 1);
        if (a <= 5) {
            a = 255;
            scatterBase.reset = false;
            //timer.stop();
            _timer.stop();
            _timeout.stop();
        }

        if (Web.isPlaying === false) {
            _timer.stop();
        }

    }));
    if (Web.isPlaying === false) {
        _timeout.stop();
    }
}, 5000);
scatterBase.timeout.push(_timeout);
};
};

scatterBase.lifeCycle = function(imgData, cx, cy, a) {

    for (var i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
        imgData.data[i + 3] = a;
    }
    scatterBase.scatter.context.putImageData(imgData, cx, cy);
};
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but you should post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ stackoverflow is generally for help fixing broken code and you'll probably get better responses over on codereview

Comment: I wouldn't set a timeout for each plot point.  I have would have a single timer that would evaluate the plot points for expiration.   If you keep your list as queue, with the ones expiring soonest at the top, it would only have to evaluate small subset of entire list.

Comment: @tatmanblue Set one timer that evaluates all the points. You may be able to sort or organize them so that it's faster to evaluate.

Comment: Also, the description and little snippet of code you've give us is not really enough to help.  This is the sort of question where a full reproducible example is needed.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak No offense taken! I now know the difference and will have to do that! My first question ever posted..

Comment: @tatmanblue perfect idea. How would you then perform the animation fade once the point has reached expiration? run a recursive loop or time out on that data point?

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure if a reproducible example could provide the the same results without the websocket.. Although i could try..